# AWS Lambda failed to resolve hostname in child_process spawn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ffmpeg

i'm trying to get ffmpeg working in AWS Lambda reading from and writing to S3. I crawled through dozens of aws documentations, stackoverflow questions and blog posts. All do it slightly different, but in the end none of them worked for me. So I hope to find help here :)
I sticked to the tutorial from  InPlainEnglish: https://plainenglish.io/community/automated-video-processing-with-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg-2834b7

The ffprobe command does work, so ffmpeg is callable. But when calling ffmpeg within a child_process.spawn command i get the error `Failed to resolve hostname my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com: System error`

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
    const s3 = new S3Client({});
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const sourceKey = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    const sourceURL = await getSignedUrl(s3, new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: sourceKey,
    }), {
        expiresIn: 900,
    });

    const tmpFilePath = 'tmp/video.mp4';
    const { convertOut } = await commander(`/opt/ffmpeg -i "${sourceURL}" -vf scale=1080:-2,format=yuv420p ${tmpFilePath}`);

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: {
            result: JSON.stringify(convertOut),
        },
    };
};
```

the signed url is fine. I've tested it with vanilla js `await fetch(sourceURL)` and it returned the file. The problem is that for some reason the child_process has no internet access.

if anyone is able to point me in the right direction i would appreciate it :D

Full error message:

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Command failed: /opt/ffmpeg -i \"https://my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/original/Testvideo.MOV?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential={redacted}&X-Amz-Date=20240209T212255Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token={redacted}&X-Amz-Signature={redacted}&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject\" -vf scale=1080:-2,crop=1080:1350,format=yuv420p tmp/video.mp4\nffmpeg version 6.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)\n  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg\n  libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100\n  libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102\n  libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100\n  libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100\n  libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100\n  libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100\n  libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100\n  libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100\n[tcp @ 0x141950d0] Failed to resolve hostname my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com: System error\n[in#0 @ 0x14190900] Error opening input: Input/output error\nError opening input file https://my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/original/Testvideo.MOV?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential={redacted}&X-Amz-Date=20240209T212255Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token={redacted}&X-Amz-Signature={redacted}&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject.\nError opening input files: Input/output error\n",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Command failed: /opt/ffmpeg -i \"https://my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/original/Testvideo.MOV?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential={redacted}&X-Amz-Date=20240209T212255Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token={redacted}&X-Amz-Signature={redacted}&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject\" -vf scale=1080:-2,crop=1080:1350,format=yuv420p tmp/video.mp4",
    "ffmpeg version 6.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers",
    "  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)",
    "  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg",
    "  libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100",
    "  libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102",
    "  libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100",
    "  libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100",
    "  libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100",
    "  libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100",
    "  libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100",
    "  libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100",
    "[tcp @ 0x141950d0] Failed to resolve hostname my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com: System error",
    "[in#0 @ 0x14190900] Error opening input: Input/output error",
    "Error opening input file https://my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/original/Testvideo.MOV?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential={redacted}&X-Amz-Date=20240209T212255Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token={redacted}&X-Amz-Signature={redacted}&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject.",
    "Error opening input files: Input/output error",
    "",
    "    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:422:12)",
    "    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)",
    "    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)",
    "    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)"
  ]
}
enter code here
```

**Update**: Turns out it is not S3 or internet, but the child_process which does not seem to have internet access. I've update my description above.

Comment: "Failed to resolve hostname my-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com: System error" Does the presigned URL work for you outside of ffmpeg?  Does the hostname fail to resolve, perhaps due to the characters in your bucket name?

Comment: When i copy the url into the browser the file gets downloaded. the bucket name is like that, two latin letter words joined by a hyphen. Lambda also has all rights to access S3. I read that lambda does not have internet access, do i need to grant lambda that right? If so, how?

Comment: Is the AWS Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, then it does not have Internet access unless you have configured a NAT Gateway in a public subnet. If the Lambda function is _NOT_ connected to a VPC, then it has full access to the Internet. You should only connect it to a VPC if it has a need to access resources in that VPC (eg a database).

Comment: Thank you, but the vpc page on the lambda configuration is empty. so it should have full internet access!? any other possible reason?

Comment: Update: I just tested it with a url pointing to my own server to read a configuration which worked. So the S3 server seems to be the problem or the `GetObjectCommand` is not the correct one for ffmpeg?

Comment: The "Failed to resolve hostname" error is not caused by S3 or IAM permissions. It's a networking or DNS issue. See [How do I troubleshoot consistent and intermittent DNS-related errors in AWS Lambda?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-intermittent-consistent-dns-error)

Comment: `System error` in conjunction with `Failed to resolve hostname` seems like an unusual combination, unlikely to be the result of no Internet (which should be impossible for the child process, in any event, if the parent has access).  I would try replacing the ffmpeg invocation with something like `curl -v 'https://my-bucket...' -o /dev/null` to see if you get a more useful error from curl than you are getting from ffmpeg. (I *think* curl will already be available in the container, and if so then you wouldn't need to bundle it.)

Comment: Try replacing `s3.amazonaws.com` in the address with the IP address (get it from `nslookup s3.amazonaws.com`). If it works, it's probably to do with the warning from John Van Sickle's build info page:

> A limitation of statically linking glibc is the loss of DNS resolution. Installing
             nscd through your package manager will fix this.

The suggested fix isn't an option AFAIK on lambda. I have the same issue currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue as you described, just using Python instead of JS. `FFmpeg` cannot resolve a host name when calling ffmpeg with a video from an url. This occurs with the statically linked  `FFmpeg` by John Van Sickle, see the [Readme](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/release-readme.txt).

As proposed in the Readme, I tried:

1. Installing `nscd`
2. Starting it in the background when the Lambda is executed.

This fixed the issue when testing the container locally but not on AWS Lambda.

However, the following option worked for me: In my Python code, I download the video from the URL and save it to a temporary file. Then, I run ffmpeg on the temporary local file. DNS resolution only fails in the statically built `FFmpeg` but not when downloading the file in Python.

Please let me know if it helps you, or when you have fixed the issue in a different way.